# How to click on the element using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to select value from drop down using adjacent sibling but does not work

Here is the Html:

```
<div id="dependsOnQuestionDiv"><div class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap" id="ext-gen197" style="width: 17px;"><input type="text" size="24" autocomplete="off" id="dependsOnQuestion" name="dependsOnQuestion" class="x-form-text x-form-field x-trigger-noedit" readonly="" title="" style="width: 345px;"><img src="/mco/extjs/resources/images/default/s.gif" alt="" class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger" id="ext-gen198"></div></div>
```

I have tried these ways:

```
(xpath =
 "//input[@id='dependsOnQuestion']/following-sibling::img[@id='ext-gen198']"
```

and

```
> css = #dependsOnQuestion ~img "
```

But it clicks on other element which has image tag

Here is another image tag HTML which is cliked when i am trying to click drop down

```
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-edit  x-action-col-cell" style="width: 41px;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-edit x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><img alt="" src="/mco/images/edit-button.png" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0  "></div></td>

<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-edit x-unselectable" unselectable="on" xpath="1"><img alt="" src="/mco/images/edit-button.png" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0 " style=""></div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: So you are looking for generic xpath or individual xpath for each element?

Comment: I am looking for  dropd down generic xpath

Answer (score 0):

Try Below `XPATH` options.

```
xpath = "//img[@id='ext-gen198']/preceding-sibling::input[@id='dependsOnQuestion']"
```

OR

```
 xpath = "//img[@id='ext-gen198']/preceding-sibling::input[1]"
```

Comment: Thanks KunduK I have tried your suggested x path but it selects another element with image tag

Comment: Can you post the HTML properly so that it would be easy to response your query?

Comment: @sap : Take some time and copy the entire tag you are looking for a valid xpath and post it properly.

Comment: @sap : The second xpath should work for you to click on input element

Comment: I have tried that one also It clicks on another element not dropdown

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#dependsOnQuestionDiv input.x-form-text.x-form-field.x-trigger-noedit#dependsOnQuestion[name='dependsOnQuestion']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='dependsOnQuestionDiv']//input[@class='x-form-text x-form-field x-trigger-noedit' and @id='dependsOnQuestion'][@name='dependsOnQuestion']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB  I have tried your suggestions but I don't know It clicks another button......Heere is another button Html........................................................................<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-edit x-unselectable" unselectable="on" xpath="1"><img alt="" src="/mco/images/edit-button.png" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0  " style=""></div>